# Could not find module ‘Text.Parsec.Number’

Tags: haskell, parsec

```
(octopus) ➜  src git:(master) ✗ ghc -o solidity-cfg-builder Main.hs
[7 of 9] Compiling CFG.Parsing      ( CFG/Parsing.hs, CFG/Parsing.o )

CFG/Parsing.hs:6:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Text.Parsec.Number’
    Perhaps you meant
      Text.Parsec.Char (from parsec-3.1.13.0)
      Text.Parsec.Error (from parsec-3.1.13.0)
      Text.Parsec.Expr (from parsec-3.1.13.0)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
6 | import Text.Parsec.Number
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `parsec` is 3.1.13, but the module `Text.Parsec.Number` cannot be found

Comment: According to [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/lts-13.0/package/parsec-3.1.13.0), such module indeed does not exist in that package. Did you mean `Text.Parsec.Numbers` from `ParsecTools`?

Answer (score 0):

There is not `Text.Parsec.Number` in `parsec`, but there is `Text.Parsec.Number` that is a copy of `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Number` from the `parsec-number` package.

[Link](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec3-numbers-0.1.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Number.html)